# May I save user id inside $_SESSION variables?

Tags: php, session, variables

Working on very big project and trying to create optimal database usage. I heard that it's not recomended to save user id's in $_SESSION variables. I can actually work with only tokens, this tokens are assigned to user id's in database. The problem is, if I will work with only tokens, I need to do 1 extra operation (query) with database inside script. So the question is, may I save user id inside $_SESSION variables to prevent ectra database operations? How "dangerous" it might be?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Who told you that you cannot save the user id in a session variable?

Comment: As dangerous as storing something in a file or in database

Comment: @EmilVikström 1 of hi-rep php guys

Comment: @epic_syntax: 100% that you didn't get them correct

Comment: @zerkms I think DB is more safe because at least it's pass protected

Comment: @epic_syntax: nope, actually the safety value (if it is even possible to compare) is the same

Comment: Please read carefullt my post, I posted `it's not recomended to save` not `I cannot`

Comment: I prefer to pull the user's data based on their ID on each page load.  What if the user changes his name in a different session or something?  You'll have a temporary mismatch.  (And the problem enters the realm of dangerous if you start storing access control stuff in sessions and not reloading it on each request.)  As far as storing a "token" goes, I'm not sure what you mean.  What's the difference in this token and the id if both grant access to the user?

Comment: Well, I'm also a hi-rep PHP guy and I don't agree. You should avoid saving the **password** in the session because you may have some bug which leaks the session to the outer world, but the user id of the currently logged-in user is not a secret at all.

Comment: @epic_syntax: depending on how you write your code - **any** solution may be either secure or not. There is no de-facto super-secured solutions

Comment: @Corbin When user changes his name, id will still stay as it was. So it will work, without anny error

Comment: What I mean is if you're doing something like using $_SESSION['name'] for messages like "Hello, Corbin".  What if the user changes his name using a different session?  (Though I suspect with the mention of token vs id that this is not what you're talking about with extra queries.)

Comment: @Corbin token changes on each login session. There is log table in my database, which basically assigns token to id

Comment: And the token is never actaully sent to the client?  Then as deceze said, you may as well use the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only impact I can see, is that somebody who has access to the file system (where php stores session data), can see which users are currently logged in. Normally this should not be a big secret - there are more interesting things on the file system. If you use tokens, the user who has access to the file system would need to have access to the DB as well to get the same information, but usually this would be easy to achieve with access to the file system.

Maybe the person who told you this meant that you should not store passwords in the Session? That of course would be dangerous.

Or he meant that you should not save user ids in cookies?

Comment: Of course, you'd be storing passwords salted and hashed to begin with, so there shouldn't be much extra risk there either, right? Right?! :)

Comment: Of course you should store passwords salted and hashed. One could argue if storing them in a session adds security issues, but it is definitely not necessary. And you'd have redundant data (db, session) of data that might change (salted PW). Might get inconsistent. Not a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you may. The session is stored on the server and therefore just about as safe as any other server-side storage.

Comment: Well, seems like words of 94k are more "trustable" than the [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869337/may-i-save-user-id-inside-session-variables#comment14161895_10869337) from 50k. Okay :-)

Comment: @zerkms Absolutely, almost twice as much. ;-P

Comment: offtop: Btw, there were ratings among the users within one particular tag. Cannot find it :-(

Comment: Got it: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers. Well, yes, to early for me to compete with top 6 guy :-)